# Search and return images on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a site that loads 1000+ small images on page at one time.  There is no text on page, just the images.  If I had a search bar at the top and wanted to filter through the images and return one based on filename or alt text.. is this possible?  with Javascript/jQuery? or maybe another means?

Any help implementing this would be awesome.

Comment: The alt text or filename is doable. What do you try?

Comment: Can be done, not sure fast it would be though. http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/7G5wx/2/) makes use of the jQuery [contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/).

Markup:

```
<img alt="abc" src="def.gif" />
<img alt="bcd" src="efg.png" />
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
<div id="results"></div>​
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('#search').change(function(){
        var s = $(this).val();
        var results = $('img[alt*="' + s + '"],img[src*="' + s + '"]');
        var output = $('<div></div>').append(results.clone());
        $('#results').text(output.html());
    });
});​
```

If you want to see the images in the results rather than the markup then change `$('#results').text(output.html());` to `$('#results').html(output.html());`. Note that this will also include the search results in the following search. Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/7G5wx/3/) the displays the search results.

Answer (score 3):

Based on photo name for example, you can search through your photos like this:

```
var photoName = "photo name";
$('img[src*="'+photoName+'"]').each(function(){
   //Do what you want with the found photos
});
```

**EDIT**

You can use others images attributes `like` alt or `title`

Comment: Make sure you take out the space after `img`

Comment: Alright have this working and sorting through the images.  I have it popping an alert if the photo src is right.  How do I get it to append an image to the #results div?

Comment: You can append pictures in your result div like this (add this code in the each callback, after your alert() function): `$('#resultDiv').append($(this).clone());`

Answer (score 1):

You can grab all image elements using:

```
var allImages = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
```

You can then check the `src` attribute to find a match.

```
var i;
var search = 'test';
var matches = [];
for (i = 0; i < allImages.length; i+) {
    if (allImages[i].src.indexOf(search) > -1) {
        matches.push(allImages[i]);
    }
}
```

So now you have an array of matches.

You can write them somewhere, like this...

```
var searchResults = document.getElementById('results');
for (i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
    searchResults.appendChild(matches[i]);
}
```

You don't have to use the `src`, you could use any attribute on the image, including your own `data-keywords` tag if you really wanted. You might want to make things a lot more clever if you allow multiple words to be entered as a search.

Here is a simple example handling multiple words, which could appear in any order:

```
var i;
var search = 'test multi word';
var searchTerms = search.split(' ');
var matches = [];

var isMatch = function (haystack, needles) {
    for (var i = 0; i < needles.length; i++) {
        if (haystack.indexOf(needles[i]) === -1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

for (i = 0; i < allImages.length; i+) {
    if (isMatch(allImages[i].src, searchTerms)) {
        matches.push(allImages[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't use JQuery selector?

Comment: Because it won't work as soon as you want to handle multiple-word-searches and it will wrap each image in a jQuery object on an operation that is already likely to slow down at scale.

Comment: Interesting remark. Are you sure that the multiple word doesn't work? The text to find is inside quote, I think it is possible, but I didn't test. In your solution, you need to loop through all images like JQuery selector.

Comment: Whether you use jQuery or not you loop through all the images. Using a jQuery selector would it find `animal zoo` in `zootripanimals.jpg`?

Answer (score 0):

(jQuery)

Well, if you had an input field,

```
$field.on('keyup', function(evt) {
  $('img:not(
      [src*="' + $(this).val() + '"],
      [src*="' + $(this).attr('alt') + '"]
   )').hide();
});
```

That might work. I haven't tried that out, but in my head it would. Basically, it would just hide everything that doesn't apply to the search term.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the HTML is structured.

If the images are included directly on IMG tags() you can find it using a code like below:

```
$("img").each(function(){
     console.log("ALT: " + $(this).attr("alt"));
     console.log("FILE PATH AND NAME: " + $(this).attr("src"));
});
```

Note that neither whenever you sees an image in the browser it is necessarily an IMG tag. The image can be the background of a CSS class, for example.